# Ho to fix app that won't debug on Android 14

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

Prior to Android 14 updates I was able to debug my app on phones. After the Android 14 update I can no longer debug on the Samsung S23 and also cannot debug on the Pixel 8 Pro.

When I select the menu item in Android Studio to "Debug App", the app is installed and launched but in the process of trying to attach to the process I get this error.

```
SIGBUS (signal SIGBUS: illegal address)
```

That's the only thing I get in the debugger window/logcat. Other apps debug fine so it's something specific to my app but I don't know what it could be. Any ideas for what could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

I've also spent a lot of time debugging this issue and I couldn't find the root cause of it. With a little help from this thread (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240007217 - same, but different issue), I found out that I can add a lldb command in the Debug configuration that will make the debug process work again without stopping on SIGBUS events.

```
Edit Configuration -> Debugger -> LLDB Post Attach Commands -> "process handle SIGBUS --pass true --stop false --notify true"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a very useful workaround. We're debugging from Visual Studio using the AGDE. Do you know how to pass these same values from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3):

I also have the same problem with the latest update of Android 14 on Pixel 8 Pro and Pixel 6 Pro. With the previous build of Android 14 it still worked without any problems. However, **it happens with the projects that contain NDK**. It can be easily reproduced using Google's simplest HelloJNI demo project. A temporary solution is to change the “Debug type” to “Java only” in the “Run/Debug configuration” of the app.

[Screenshot of the debug log window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTFOY.png)

Comment: There's and Endless Tunnel example from the AGDE site that uses NDK and it debugs fine on these devices. So I'm not sure it's purely an NDK related thing. I'd love to find the root cause but it's been very difficult to debug.

Comment: Same issue here. Tried using NDK 26 and it made no difference.