# Android Studio Debugger immediately crashes

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a functioning Android NDK application that I want to debug with the Android Studio Debugger on a rooted device. When I start the debugger, it immediately crashes with a `SIGBUS (signal SIGBUS: illegal address)` error in `libart.so`.

What exactly is happening when the debugger gets initialized for the application? Where could this problem arise from?

Comment: Is there a question you'd like to ask?

Comment: @BillHorvath Sorry, I just edited the question accordingly

Comment: See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77837403/ho-to-fix-app-that-wont-debug-on-android-14/